# How can I ensure that the background worker service and the razor component are using same cache of EF data?

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

Environment:

- Blazor
- net8.0-windows
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.1

I have a background service that every few seconds checks the status of a printer and updates the `IsReady` property of a `LabelPrinter` Entity Framework Core entity that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanging` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` interfaces.

I have a razor component that obtains the `LabelPrinter` entity and subscribes to the `OnPropertyChanging` and `OnPropertyChanged` events.

The problem is that when the printer changes state the `OnPropertyChanging` and `OnPropertyChanged` events fire correctly, but when they fire, the list of event subscribers is always empty; the event handlers in the razor component are never called.

This led me to believe that the EF Core entity that the background service is updating is not the same entity that the razor component is monitoring for changes. I read that, "If the service and the razor are using the same `IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>` with dependency injection (DI), they are not necessarily using the same cache of data. This is because the `IDbContextFactory` creates a new `DbContext` instance every time the `CreateDbContext` method is called. Therefore, each `DbContext` instance will have its own cache and may not reflect the changes made by other instances. However, if you want to share the same cache of data between the service and the razor, you can use the scope parameter of the `AddDbContextFactory` method. This parameter allows you to specify a custom service provider that will be used to resolve the `DbContext` dependencies. By using the same service provider for both the service and the razor, you can ensure that they will use the same `DbContext` instance and the same cache of data.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    ,lifetime: ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

I can't get this to work. How can I ensure that the background worker service and the razor component are using same cache of EF Core data such that the event handlers are called correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `lifetime: ServiceLifetime.Scoped` incorrectly:

The `lifetime` parameter for `AddDbContextFactory` specifies the lifetime of the `DbContextFactory` and not the lifetime of any `DbContext` objects it creates.

...which is why `AddDbContextFactory` uses `Singleton` by default - [c.f. the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontextfactory?view=efcore-8.0#:%7E:text=The%20lifetime%20with%20which%20to%20register%20the%20factory%20and%20options.%20The%20default%20is%20Singleton):

> **`lifetime`** `ServiceLifetime`
> The lifetime with which to register the factory and options. The default is `Singleton`

So this means that *for every request (or scope)* a brand new, entirely separate, `AddDbContextFactory` will be created and (AFAIK) that any configured EF cache will only be shared by `DbContext` instances created by that scoped factory - hence the problem you're experiencing.

**To fix this, change your `AddDbContextFactory` call to use `Singleton`**.

Note that this doesn't stop you from *also* having your `DbContext` registered as a `Scoped` service; [in fact, `AddDbContextFactory` does this for you anyway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontextfactory?view=efcore-8.0#:%7E:text=For%20convenience%2C%20this%20method%20also%20registers%20the%20context%20type%20itself%20as%20a%20scoped%20service.%20This%20allows%20a%20context%20instance%20to%20be%20resolved%20from%20a%20dependency%20injection%20scope%20directly%20or%20created%20by%20the%20factory%2C%20as%20appropriate.):

> For convenience, this method **also** registers the context type itself as a scoped service. This allows a context instance to be resolved from a dependency injection scope directly or created by the factory, as appropriate.

---

Note that your `DbContext` should really be always constructable, especially when *outside* of DI's scoped context, which means you can't depend on services that are only available in a request-scope. So if you are only using `Singleton` and/or `Transient` dependencies in your `DbContext`'s constructor, then that's okay.

Comment: Dai, thank you for the awesome response to my question.  I changed the service lifetime for DbContextFactory to singleton and still have the same behavior in that it appears that the background service and the razor component are working off of different EF data caches.

Comment: I first hit the breakpoint where the razor component subscribes to the OnPropertyChanging, OnPropertyChanged events of the entity; then    when the OnPropertyChanging, OnPropertyChanged events fire on the entity there aren't any event subscribers.  I think this is telling me that there are two different EF data caches at work.

Comment: @Will Use your debugger to look inside the `DbContext` instance - and its consumer - and check `Object.ReferenceEquals( dbContextCache, otherCache )` - and to find out where (in memory) they are.